# immediate redirect after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I want to add some infos to a database. If the database has already some info, you may not add some infos.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#RDpage",function(){  
    $("#submitR").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://xxx:8080/getRD", function(data) {

            if (data.length == 0) {
                // send data to server
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://xxx:8080/addRD",
                    type: 'GET',
                    contenttype:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: {
                        user:user,
                        RD:"Test"
                   },
                   dataType:'JSON'
                });
                $.mobile.changePage("#dialogAddRD", { transition: "pop", role: "dialog" });
            } else {
                $.mobile.changePage("#dialogExistingRD", { transition: "pop", role: "dialog" });
            }

        });
    })
});
```

Actually it works, BUT not the redirect.

I click on the button, it sends the data to the server and the **dialogAddRD appears for 1 second**. I can't click on it. Then I will be redirected back to the RDpage.

Normally, the dialog should remains open and then, I can click a button to go to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax-function is asynchronous and will return a promise. As mentioned in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you would use it like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://xxx:8080/addRD",
    type: 'GET',
    contenttype:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {
        user:user,
        RD:"Test"
   },
   dataType:'JSON'
})
.done(function( data ) {
    $.mobile.changePage("#dialogAddRD", { transition: "pop", role: "dialog" });
});
```